# Вопросы вывода и зарабатывания денег

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, тематика

На сайте есть несколько вопросов, не имеющих прямого отношения к программированию и администрированию, но тесно с ними связанные. Это - вопросы, относящиеся к магазинам приложений - *Google Play*, *AppStore*, *Магазин Windows* и т.п.

В частности, есть вопросы о зарабатывании и выводе денег из этих магазинов:

- [Вывод денег из аккаунтов Google Play и AdMob](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/383937)
- [Регистрация аккаунта разработчика Google Play и вывод денег в России](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/387921)
- [Регистрация в Google Play, оплата взноса, подтверждение личности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478444)
- [Как несовершеннолетним подросткам зарабатывать в Google Play?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496279)

С одной стороны, это вопросы не о программировании. Но если посмотреть с другой - то эти вопросы касаются одной из неотъемлемых сторон профессионального программирования - получения оплаты за свою работу.

Хотелось бы знать мнение сообщества. Уместны ли вопросы такого рода на *ruSO*?

Comment: На мете не стоит ставить зеленую галку так быстро, да еще и не дождавшись хоть какого-то альтернативного решения. :)

Comment: Какой желтый заголовок :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Я считаю, что вполне уместны (по крайней мере настолько же, насколько уместны вопросы о видах лицензий для программ).

Если кто-то разбирается, пусть поделится своим опытом. IMHO хуже от этого никому не будет.

Answer (score 7):

Эти вопросы крайне важны и нужны. Мне не представить себе лучшего для них места, чем здесь. Вердикт - оставить все и неистово плюсовать. При этом для половины приведённых вопросов есть хорошие ответы. Я лично проверял их достоверность и они полностью соответствуют действительности, а также хорошо оформлены.

Comment: И не обращайте внимание, что один из приведённых вопросов - мой, а ещё на 2 я ответы давал)

Comment: Может быть стоило просто собрать все три вопроса в один большой вопрос-ответ, чтобы снизить уровень оффтопичности? Например, на основе самого заплюсованного ответа.

Comment: @PashaPash, хорошая идея. Как-нибудь на досуге займусь)

Comment: @PashaPash ... и станет их на один больше :D

Comment: @Qwertiy а остальные - удалить....

Comment: @PashaPash, не надо удалять) Они же мне дороги)

Answer (score 5):

Три первых вопроса по сути - дубликаты.

На мой взгляд, с этими вопросами стоит поступить точно так же, как с вопросами по книгам - объединить в один общий вопрос-ответ.