# Новый сайт на движке StackExchange на русском языке про бизнес и общество

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Так как спрос есть, но нет предложения, то вот пробуем запустить очередной сайт на движке StackExchange на русском языке (Society, Business and Law in Russia) https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95937/society-business-and-law-in-russia

Подписывайтесь, нажимайте плюсы, комментируйте и рекламируйте. Так будет больше шансов на запуск у нового сайта.

Примеры спроса:

- [Вопросы вывода и зарабатывания денег](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2606/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3)
- [Где задавать не IT-шные вопросы на движке StackExchange?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/708/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-it-%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B5-stackexchange)
- [Как создать русскоязычный сайт на StackExchange?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1253/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-stackexchange)

**Обновлено**

Предложение не актуально, так как администрация SE не располагает ресурсами для поддержания не англоязычных сайтов. Отсюда, такой вопрос к администрации SO RU, в чем секрет вашего успеха для запуска и что можно с этим поделать?

Comment: Секрета нет. Для компании [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/company/about), сайты для программистов являются главным продуктом. Английская версия приносит больше траффика (и намного больше дохода) чем все остальные сайты вместе взятые. Отсюда и  приоритет.

Comment: Неужели вы не прочитали ответы на вопросы, на которые дали ссылки?

Answer (score 7):

Для тех, кому всё-таки интересно, почему существует русскоязычные сайты SO и Русский язык, несмотря на ограничения по языку (только English), предлагаю почитать [интервью](https://vc.ru/p/knowledge-network-stack-overflow) от основателя этих сайтов.